# Why does not the variable in the while loop, change the boolean from True to False?

Tags: python

Why does not the variable **check** in the while loop, change the boolean from True to False?

```
def word_valid():
    words = input("Your word: ").upper()

    global check
    check = False
    return words

def main():
    check = True
    while check is True:
        words = word_valid()
    print(words) #Won't print out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `global` takes from the global scope, but `check` isn't in the global scope, it's in `main`'s scope

Comment: I see. Is here a way to make it work without deleting **def main()**?

Comment: tbh on a little searching, what i said may be _slightly_ misleading (though the three upvotes are making me doubt myself further). Overall, unless you know for sure you want `global` (or you're just trying to work out what it does), I'd avoid it

Comment: If I have a valid word, I do not want to search for more. So it means, I want to **break** the while loop. I do not know, how can it work without the **global** yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` refers to the global scope, but the `check` in `main` is local to `main`'s scope. That is, the `check` you're mutating in `word_valid` is a different `check` to the one in `main`

Without thinking too much about how to do this nicely, you could return `check`

```
def word_valid():
    words = input("Your word: ").upper()

    check = False
    return words, check

def main():
    check = True
    while check is True:
        words, check = word_valid()
    print(words) #Won't print out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```